# with bat file: open excel within existing (already open) instance of excel

Tags: excel, batch-file

I have an excel workbook open and I want a .bat file to open a workbook within that same instance of excel. How do I do it? In other words, an excel workbook is already open in one instance of excel and I want to open another workbook with a .bat file script, but I do not want to create another instance of excel. Both workbooks should be open in the same instance of excel.

Here is what I am doing now, which doesn't work:
Excel workbook 1 is already open (manually), instance 1 of excel (excel.exe) is already open (manually). At some point later in time my .bat file starts running via Task Scheduler. My .bat file code looks like this:

```
REM open excel workbook
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Excel.exe" "Y:\somepath\somefilename.xlsm"
EXIT
```

...and instance 2 of excel.exe is created with "somefilename" open in it, which is wrong.

I need just one instance of excel.exe and both files/workbooks open in that one instance and I have to open the second file with a .bat file (for reasons that are frustrating, but necessary). No other languages, just batch please. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you can do it by batch file only. But in VBS, you can `GetObject(,"Excel.Application")` to grab an existing Excel process and control it.

Comment: Have you tried to, instead of calling excel, start the workbook? that is `start "" "Y:\somepath\somefilename.xlsm"`

Comment: MC ND - start "" "Y:\somepath\somefilename.xlsm" works perfectly. Many thanks!

Comment: @MCND,  When the spreadsheet is open by another user, I get an error in the cmd.exe window "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." Whereas if I open a .xlsx file and it's locked by another user, Excel offers to open it ready only (among other options). Is there a way to get this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MC ND's comment on my original question is correct:

```
start "" "Y:\somepath\somefilename.xlsm"
```

...works perfectly.